# Migrating data from ACF to WordPress custom meta boxes

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, migration

I’m currently re-developing a theme for WordPress Multisite. The homepage and gallery template both use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

So I can fully maintain the theme moving forward, I would like to replace ACF with native WordPress custom meta boxes. For those already using the theme on Multisite, is it possible to migrate the data from ACF to my new custom meta boxes?

I'm not looking for quick a solution, just any advice you can give me on migrations of this type.

Comment: ACF uses post meta in the normal way so you should be able to simply define meta boxes for the fields defined in ACF and it will work that way.  Why do you want to get rid of ACF though? It's super well maintained / supported and makes working with post meta / custom fields much easier/faster as a developer than "rolling your own".

Comment: Thanks @Ennui, that's good to know. To answer your question, I'm challenging myself to build a theme without the aid of any plugins. This will hopefully improve my development skills and help me understand WP inside out.

Comment: Use native method. get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );

Comment: There is also the whole ACF conflicts with other plugins and just plain prevents any custom tinyMCE plugins from working. Did this ever get resolved? or is the answer to just `get_post_meta` ?